# Laravel 5.1 deployement with Envoy cd: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, laravel-envoy

I am trying to deploy my laravel 5.1 with Envoy when I try to run envoy run deploy I get the following error:

cd: /home/spark/: Permission denied

this means deploybot has no permission to access my project folder how can I give deploybot permission?

Thanks in advance for your help!

My envoy.blade.php

```
@servers( ['production' => 'deploybot@*domainnameplaceholder*' ])

@task('deploy', ['on' => 'production'])
 cd /home/spark/
 php artisan down
 git reset --hard HEAD
 git pull origin master
 php composer.phar dump-autoload
 php artisan migrate --force
 php artisan up
@endtask
```

The permissions on the /home/spark dir

```
drwxr-x--- 13 apache    apache    4096 Nov 23 17:57 spark
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add deploybot to your apache group.

```
useradd -G apache deploybot
```

Comment: should that be `www-data` instead?